# Linux Mint : How do I connect to WiFi via WPS?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, wps

I am running Linux Mint 21.

How do I connect to a WPS capable router via WPS ?

I know WPS is insecure but that's kind of the point since it was the only way for me to connect to the internet as I did not have the router's password when I needed it.

All solutions I have seen so far seem outdated ans require various complex steps/custom scripts or config files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an rather easy way to do it although it requires firing up a terminal.
In the terminal, enter `nmcli connection modify $YOUR_WIFI_CONNECTION wifi-sec.wps-method pbc`
(You may be able to tab your way into finding the connection name depending on your shell)

Now, push the WPS button on your router, then just connect to $YOUR_WIFI_CONNECTION. It may ask for a password, don't enter any, just wait for it to connect automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how shall I modify YOUR_WIFI_CONNECTION before I'm connected to my router? There is no connection, "nmcli connection show" shows nothing for wifi

Comment: @Achim Can't check right now but IIRC `nmcli dev wifi` should give you the list of available connections. Maybe go read the `man nmcli` if that doesn't work